# Как передать картинку с камеры в POST запрос?

Tags: android, java

Нужно запихать картинку с камеры в POST запрос, чтобы переслать на сервер? Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @kaaa, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Вот ваш рецепт счастья:    

 1. Google - Android take picture from camera 
 2. Google - Android post request send image

Готово!

Comment: Я получаю картинку с камеры устройства, сохраняю (например) и хочу ее отправить на сервер используя post запрос. Хотелось бы увидеть кусок кода (JAVA), который позволит мне это сделать. Если есть другие варианты, не через post, готов их рассмотреть.

Comment: Что бы увидеть кусок кода, войдите в гугл и наберите Android post request send image. нажмите на первую ссылку в выдаче, и, о чудо, там будет кусок кода!

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Вроде нашел по этому запросу. Буду разбираться и пробовать.

Comment: @kaaa вот неплохая библиотека для работы с сетью Посмотрите раздел POST TO A SERVER http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Получилось используя библиотеку android-async-http-1.4.6.jar

Comment: А потом и появляются такие кодеры, которые без сторонней либы базовую задачу решить не смогут.

[Решение со стандартным пакетом org.apache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126724/2718135)

Comment: @SuperCreeper Google попросили не использовать больше AndroidHttpClient, а вместо этого юзать UrlConnection. И в целом не вижу ничего плохого в использовании качественной библиотеки.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, детский лепет! Нужно `new Socket("host", 80);` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот так и получилось отправить картинку на сервер в post запросе.

```
public void UplPhoto(String strURL){
    SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("text", "some string");
    try {
        params.put("image", new File("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    client.post(MAIN_URL + "/mapi/photo.php", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
        }
    });
}
```