# Отправка изображения на сайт

Tags: php, java, android, json, xml

Я относительно недавно начал изучать програмирование под андроид..
По этому у меня возник вопрос: как происходит вигрузка изображений на сайт в андроид приложениях.. типа как в приложениях вк, ок и т.д. при загрузке фотографии профиля например.
В идеале нужен кусок кода для примера..
Либо хоть ссылки какие дайте, либо хоть в какую сторону копать подскажите.

Comment: Зависит от сервера. В каком виде он ждёт это изображение.

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/

Answer (score 0):

Вот схожий вопрос и рабочий ответ: [Как передать картинку с камеры в POST запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408796/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

Post запросом отправляем на свой сайт изображение, в photo.php принимаем его

```html
public void UplPhoto(String strURL){
    SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("text", "some string");
    try {
        params.put("image", new File("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    client.post(MAIN_URL + "/mapi/photo.php", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
        }
    });
}
```

Post запросом отправляем на свой сайт изображение, в photo.php принимаем его